# Plugin for custom horizontal line Y-axis marker on grid of a Line chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, chart.js

I need to create "up" and "low" markers on along the Y-axis of my Chart.js line chart. I can't seem to find an out-of-the-box way of doing this.  Anybody can help me on how to write a plugin to achieve something like this? (See the horizontal red lines along the 70 and 50 Y-axis.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a plugin called [Chart.Annotations.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.Annotation.js) on the [Chart.js GitHub root page](https://github.com/chartjs). It is exactly what I needed!

You need to add the following attributes to your options object. Add an *annotations:* attribute per line you want to draw. In my case I had 2.

```
annotation: {
annotations: [{
    type:'line',
    mode:'horizontal',
    scaleID:'y-axis-1',
    value:'10',
    borderColor:'#000000',
    borderWidth:2
}]
}
```

Look at this screenshot of my final implementation:
[image]